# Service Injected on startup is null in Extension Service Configuration aspnet core

Tags: asp.net-core, singleton

Service Injected on startup is null in Extension Service Configuration ASP.NET Core
We have one service for userservice to save user profiles and it is injected as scoped on startup.
In our extension, we add another service for students as singleton to insert update delete users' transactions. We want student info from userservice but in our student service it showing null.

In Startup.

```cs
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
```

In Extension

```cs
public void Execute(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    serviceCollection.AddMvc();

    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IStudenService, StudenService>();
}
```

In Student Service

```cs
public class StudentSerivce : IStudentSerivce
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public StudentSerivce(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService; // is null
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you adding the service in the `ConfigureServices` method? Could you please post the `IStudentService` code?

Comment: Yes,startup.cs                                                                                         
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {          
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
......    Istudent code. 
namespace HInterfaces
{
    public interface IStudentService
    {
     StudentViewModel GetRequestBySerialNumber(string reqSerialNumber);

    long NewRequest(StudentViewModel  sRequest);

Comment: You are passing IUserService but the interface name is IStudentService. Please post the IUserService code... thanks

Comment: IStudent Service is nothing just select/update/delete to db using entity framework. Question is I should have object of UserService in Student Service because UserService is initiated in startup.cs upon a request and same request is going to StudentService , why it is null? Why i cant able to use UserService in Extensions

Comment: you can't have that object thru DI if you didn't set a getter for it. follow this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```cs
public StudentService(IServiceProvider services)
{
    Services = services;
}

public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

public void SomeMethod()
{
    using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var userService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

It would probably be better to make them both scoped or both singletons (then it would work without manually creating a scope).

> It's dangerous to resolve a scoped service from a singleton. It may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests.

Reference: [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#singleton)

Comment: we cant make both singleton.userservice is to save user profile on each request n for every request. Student can be singleton because each user request or login to Student Portal website.

Comment: That's fine - then you just need to create a scope in your `StudentService` method to get access to the scoped `IUserService` every time you need it.